# How to align three figures in multiple rows an colums using subfigures (two in first column, and one on the side)

Tags: graphics, captions, subcaption, subfig

I want the following layout for my figures:

[image]

And this is my code right now:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
        \label{fig:a}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:interference}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth} 
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
        \caption{} 
        \label{fig:Bragg}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

How can I modify this to fit the layout I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

First two `subfigure`s are in `minipage`, third is right of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove "demo"
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex,
            belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:interference}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:Bragg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagefile}
      \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}

  \vspace{5mm}

  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagefile}
    \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagefile}
      \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1c}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```